# Multilingual site and views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, translate

I have content type: (filed_name1_en, field_name1_de, filed_name2_en, field_name2_de) and I want to make view so that if enter site in English that view must display (filed_name1_en, filed_name2_en) fields and if i enter site in German it must to display (filed_name1_de, filed_name2_de).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too complicated.

Just create the 'Content Types' you need, then the 'Views' to support them, and turn on the Content Translation, and Locale modules.

Keep It Simple.

Comment: Actualy i have not content type. i have this field in users profile. it will be confuse for site users to transalte his profails and i dont need to translate evry field

Comment: Follow @MuhammadReda 's tutorial.
And yes, I changed my Display Name to Ganginator from Jesse Gangi.

Answer (score 1):

As @JesseGangi said; Your making it too complicated.

Follow [this tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/275705). It will walk you through the best practice to build a multilingual website.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this task by making (overloading) views tpl file. without many changes.